# BufferReader to write new file with previous info

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

This is the basis of my code. It prints students grades on the console, but how do I use a Buffereader to put all the students grade on a new file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WorkSpace {

private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner (new File ("grades.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }}



    public void createFile()throws IOException {


        try{
            File file = new File("grades.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);




        while(s.hasNext()){
        {
            String [] split = s.nextLine().split(", ");

            String fname = split[0];

            Double q1 = Double.parseDouble (split[1]);
            Double q2 = Double.parseDouble (split[2]);
            Double q3 = Double.parseDouble (split[3]);
            Double q4 = Double.parseDouble (split[4]);
            Double proji = Double.parseDouble (split[5]);
            Double projii = Double.parseDouble (split[6]);
            Double projiii = Double.parseDouble (split[7]);

            double studentgrade = (q1 *0.1) + (q2 *0.1) +(q3 *0.1) + (q4 *0.1) +(proji*0.15) + (projii * 0.2) + (projiii *0.25);
            if(studentgrade>90)
                System.out.printf("%s got an A\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>80)
                System.out.printf("%s got a B\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>70)
                System.out.printf("%s got a C\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>60)
                System.out.printf("%s got a D\n", fname);
            else if(studentgrade>50)
                System.out.printf("%s got a F\n", fname);


        }}}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at ReadFile.readFile(ReadFile.java:22)
 at Project3.main(Project3.java:15)

Comment: from above,class Project3 is NOT calling readFile(). where did you got that error? provide the appropriate stack trace for your project.

Answer (score 0):

How you are reading your file is incorrect. The most common way to read files with scanner:

```
try{
File file = new File("Your/File/Path");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
s.useDelimiter("\n");//splits the whole file's text by "\n"
while(s.hasNext()){
String next = s.next();
//parse your stuff
}
s.close();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Also, `scanner.nextInt()` doesn't return the file's length. That was the problem. Use `file.length` to get the file's length.

Comment: Looks like you changed it to the while loop! plz upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.nextInt() returns next integer value read from source (not source length or something). You open the file and try to read integer in the beginning, but the file doesn't start with integer so you get an exception.

Comment: how can  fix this with still being able to parse all the strings/doubles?

Comment: First of all, remove int numTimes = file.nextInt(). Then change your for loop to while loop like in 11yearoldjavaguy's example. Change his String next = s.next(); to  String [] split = file.nextLine().split(" "); and operate on split like you did before.

Comment: once i do that how do i continue using my for loop?

Comment: What kind of error is it? Can you print stack trace? And what your grades.txt file looks like?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100,"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
 at ReadFile.readFile(ReadFile.java:35)
 at Project3.main(Project3.java:15)

Comment: Hardy B. Boy 90 90 100

Comment: Jeff Johnson 70 78 80

Comment: Do you need double values? Try to change Double types to int and Double.parseDouble() to Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. `BufferedReader` doesn't write files. It, err, reads files. What you want is, err, a `BufferedWriter.`